# Redirect direct url to the file only with token

Tags: php, laravel, download, token, cdn

I'm working on a project and to access the files, the user must have an account and then, he can access to the file and download it when he pay for that.

For example, I have a file like this: [here](https://dl.example.com/file.zip)

As you know, the user can copy the address in browser and simply get the file and download it.
But I want the url be like this: [here](https://dl.example.com/file.zip?token=123456abcdefg)

And without the token, he cannot access to the file and `download` it.
How can I do that in PHP? I'm using Laravel for this project.

Thank you.

Comment: better use route with code instead of show url file. example : https://dl.example.com/file/A62dgadadg34gsg, then process in your controller file with that code and force download file use this [downloading files](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#downloading-files)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do it like this....
in blade 

    <a href="{{route('your route here',\Illuminate\Support\Str::random(6))}}">Download</a>
in web.php

Route::get('your_ul/{token}', 'HomeController@download')->name('your_route');
in controller

public function download($token)
    {
        //your operation here
    }
```

And if you want more secure then first save a token in the database and when a user clicks into the button pop up a modal and ask a pin and **in the controller** do it like this

```
public function download(Request $request)
    {
        //your operation here
        $token = Download::first();
        
        if ($token == $request->token){
            ///do you download here
        }
        else
            return abort(403);
    }
```

Comment: Nope, that's not my problem. My problem isn't to set a token for download link and it's done. My problem is this: When we start downloading, we can get the real url of the file. Even when we pass the token with that, user will be able to see the file path and simply he can copy the url and send that to his friend. I wanna do something, that user be forced to send the token to url, without token, he just redirects back.

Comment: yes thats why i give you the second phase where before downloading, the user have to enter the token......and if you want a new token everytime after downloadf for the first time ...then you can delete the token from the database and before download generate a new one